# Secure way to store a number of SQL queries for an online dashboard?

Tags: php, sql, security, dashboard

I am developing a PHP project which will utilise a number of SQL queries. I would like these queries to be organised in such a way that they can be easily found and edited - for this reason I do not want to code them into the pages themselves.

I was considering keeping each query in a separate php file stored in high directory, only accessible at server level, and using `require('filename.php')` in my code.

Is this secure or are there better methods?

Comment: You could store them in a table on the database.  This could allow you to add things like user permissions etc. to each query.

Comment: You can also have a look at Stored Procedures, so you can store the queries in the DB itself. Placing them in a separate PHP file would work, too, but you have to make sure to not forget to back it up, too, when making backups. And user permissions have to be set carefully, so that not just anyone can change the file.